# How can I terminate a system command with alarm in Perl?

Tags: perl, system, alarm

I am running the below code snippet on Windows. The server starts listening continuously after reading from  client. I want to terminate this command after a time period.

If I use [alarm()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) function call within `main.pl`, then it terminates the whole Perl program (here `main.pl`), so I called this [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command by placing it in a separate Perl file 
and calling this Perl file (`alarm.pl`) in the original Perl File using the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command.

But in this way I was unable to take the output of this `system()` call neither in the original Perl File nor in  called one Perl File.

Could anybody please let me know  the way to terminate a `system()` call or take the output in that way I used above?

#### main.pl

```
my @output = system("alarm.pl");
print"one iperf completed\n";

open FILE, ">display.txt" or die $!; 
print FILE @output_1; 
close FILE;
```

#### alarm.pl

```
alarm 30;
my @output_1 = readpipe("adb shell cd /data/app; ./iperf -u -s -p 5001");

open FILE, ">display.txt" or die $!; 
print FILE @output_1; 
close FILE;
```

In both ways `display.txt` is always empty.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few separate issues here.

First, to keep the [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) from killing your script, you need to handle the ALRM signal. See the [alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) documentation. You shouldn't need two scripts for this.

Second, [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) doesn't capture output. You need one of the backtick variants or a pipe if you want to do that. There are answers for that on Stackoverflow already.

Third, if *alarm.pl* puts anything in *display.txt*, you discard it in *main.pl* when you re-open the file in write mode. You only need to create the file in one place. When you get rid of the extra script, you won't have this problem.

I recently had some problems with `alarm` and `system`, but [switching to IPC::System::Simple](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2010/03/ipcsystemsimple-a-success-story.html) fixed that.

Good luck, :)

Comment: Well, I've actually been working on this problem this week, so I was primed for it.

Comment: as you mentioned , i tried to use one single file main.pl,and using readpipe() instead of system()to capture the output in a txt file.
my @output_1 = readpipe("iperf -u -s -p 5001");
open FILE, ">display.txt" or die $!; 
print FILE @output_1; 
close FILE;
after the execution of readpipe command it hangs at below and here i
[  3]  0.0-10.7 sec    301 KBytes    231 Kbits/sec
want to come out of this readpipe command and take theoutput to a txt file but i don;t know how to handle the alarm function here could you please elaborate much w.r.t my code snippet above.

Answer (score 9):

What the hell was I thinking? You don't need a background process for this task. You just need to follow the example in the [`perldoc -f alarm`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#alarm) function and wrap your time-sensitive code in an `eval` block.

```
my $command = "adb shell cd /data/app; ./iperf -u -s -p 5001";
my @output;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" };
    alarm 30;
    @output = `$command`;
    alarm 0;
};
if ($@) {
    warn "$command timed out.\n";
} else {
    print "$command successful. Output was:\n", @output;
}
```

Inside the `eval` block, you can capture your output the regular way (with backticks or `qx()` or `readpipe`). Though if the call times out, there won't be any output.

<strike>If you don't need the output (or don't mind hacking some interprocess communication together),   an almost idiot-proof alternative is to set the alarm and run the `system` call in a child process.</strike>

```
$command = "adb shell cd /data/app; ./iperf -u -s -p 5001";
if (($pid = fork()) == 0) {
    # child process
    $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" }; # handling SIGALRM in child is optional
    alarm 30;
    my $c = system($command);
    alarm 0;
    exit $c >> 8;  # if you want to capture the exit status
}
# parent
waitpid $pid, 0;
```

`waitpid` will return when either the child's `system` command is finished, **or** when the child's alarm goes off and kills the child. `$?` will hold the exit code of the system call, or something else (142 on my system) for an unhandled SIGALRM or 255 if your SIGALRM handler calls `die`.

Comment: i am running this program on windows using Perl interpreter , are you sure will this be ok on windows,
btw where is output is getting captured of system command?

rocky..

Comment: @rockyurock -- updated my answer. Use `qx` or `readpipe` or backticks if you want to capture output.

Comment: @mob - Is there a way this can be modified so that instead of terminating after the timeout it will instead terminate when the user presses a button on the keyboard or types "exit" for example? thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I run into a similar problem that requires:

- run a system command and get its output
- time out the system command after x seconds
- kill the system command process and all child processes

After much reading about Perl IPC and manual fork & exec, I came out with this solution.  It is implemented as a simulated 'backtick' subroutine.

```
use Error qw(:try);

$SIG{ALRM} = sub {
    my $sig_name = shift;
    die "Timeout by signal [$sig_name]\n";
};

# example
my $command = "vmstat 1 1000000";
my $output = backtick( 
                 command => $command, 
                 timeout => 60, 
                 verbose => 0 
             );

sub backtick {

    my %arg = (
        command => undef,
        timeout => 900,
        verbose => 1,
        @_,
    );

    my @output;

    defined( my $pid = open( KID, "-|" ) )
        or die "Can't fork: $!\n";

    if ($pid) {

        # parent

        # print "parent: child pid [$pid]\n" if $arg{verbose};

        try {
            alarm( $arg{timeout} );
            while (<KID>) {
                chomp;
                push @output, $_;
            }

            alarm(0);
        }
        catch Error with {
            my $err = shift;
            print $err->{-text} . "\n";

            print "Killing child process [$pid] ...\n" if $arg{verbose};
            kill -9, $pid;
            print "Killed\n" if $arg{verbose};

            alarm(0);
        }
        finally {};
    }
    else {

        # child

        # set the child process to be a group leader, so that
        # kill -9 will kill it and all its descendents
        setpgrp( 0, 0 );

        # print "child: pid [$pid]\n" if $arg{verbose};
        exec $arg{command};
        exit;
    }

    wantarray ? @output : join( "\n", @output );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Might use "timeout -n  " for wrapping your commands if thats already common on your system.